# How do I make a Discord bot respond to a message with a custom emoji in on_message

Tags: python, python-requests, bots, discord, discord.py

How am I able to make my bot respond when a cutstom server emoji is in the string?
My code currently looks like this:

```
if message.content.startswith(":emoji: Hello"):
      await client.get_channel(123456789).send("Hello to you, too!")
```

If I post the emoji and the sentence in Discord, the command won't trigger. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a custom emoji, it has a unique ID, and this is what appears in the message's content, not just the name of the emoji. You can access this in a couple of different ways, but the easiest might be `\:emoji:`, which you can see working here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

And the final part is what the message's content is going to contain. So in my case, the correct statement would look like:

```py
if message.content.lower().startswith("<:statue:709925980029845565> hello"):
    await message.channel.send("Hello to you too!") # sends to the same channel the message came from
```

You can also retrieve the emoji without using its ID:

```py
emoji = discord.utils.get(message.guild.emojis, name="statue")
if message.content.lower().startswith(f"{emoji} hello"):
    await message.channel.send("Hello to you too!")
```

Note that I also used `.lower()` which makes the command case-insensitive, so it'll work whether the user types `HelLo`, `HELLO` or `hElLo`

---

**References:**

- [`Guild.emojis`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.emojis)
- [`str(emoji)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Emoji)
- [`utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get) - You can also use [`Guild.fetch_emoji()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_emoji), but this requires you to know the ID beforehand.